# RxJava computation explosion

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm facing to a tricky issue with combineLatest.
i'm building a huge chain of combineLatest and starting from the second item from my main observable, there is an explosion of the computation.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.observers.TestSubscriber;
import rx.subjects.PublishSubject;
import rx.subjects.Subject;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class RxTest {

    private AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private AtomicInteger ai2 = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Test
    public void explosion() {
        Subject<Integer, Integer> sub = PublishSubject.create();
        Observable<Integer> ret = getObservable(2, sub);

        TestSubscriber<Integer> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<Integer>();
        ret.subscribe(testSubscriber);

        sub.onNext(1);
        sub.onNext(2); // may be commented
        sub.onCompleted();

        testSubscriber.assertNoErrors();

        List<Integer> numbers = testSubscriber.getOnNextEvents();

        System.out.println(numbers.size());
        System.out.println(ai);
        System.out.println(ai2);
    }

    private Observable<Integer> getObservable(int depth, Observable<Integer> source) {
        if (depth == 0) {
            return source;
        } else {
            Observable<Integer> o = getObservable(depth - 1, source);
            for (int i = 0; i < 300; ++i) {
                ai2.incrementAndGet();
                o = Observable.combineLatest(
                        o,
                        getObservable(depth - 1, source).map((a) -> {
                            ai.incrementAndGet();
                            return a;
                        }),
                        (a, b) -> a + b
                );
            }
            return o;
        }
    }
}
```

With only one item, I have:

```
1
90600
90600
```

With two:

```
90602 
271200
90600
```

It seems to be the normal behaviour of RX. But I'm trying to know if it is possible to avoid this kind of explosion. My goal is to have this kind of output (like recreate the chain for each value)

```
2 
181200
90600
```

This code is an example of my problem not a real use case.

I'm facing to the fact that building the observable is quick(and having the first value from the observable) but if i'm changing the "leaf" observable, it's not.

Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here, but can't you replace the second argument in `combineLatest` with `o.map((a) -> { .... })`? Seems like you are doing a lot of extra recursion because of the second call to `getObservable`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the recursion? Recursive directory traversal? Currently, there is no efficient operator available for 1.x but there is for 2.x in the RxJava2Extensions library: expand.

Comment: The recursion is only used in order to simulate a tree. No I can't replace by map because in my real code a node can evolve following the "leaf" observable. I need to build a tree according to observable leaf. The issue here is that multiple node use the same "leaf" observable. One leaf change produce lot of tree instead of just one (propaging from leaf to root)

Comment: I finally manage to find how to do that. The issue is that a change of the inputs combineLatest (of two same observable), emits two elements, I must have only one element(which is not absurde). For reach that I made few modifications. 
- Use a scheduler which serializes actions (no parallel)
- Use this scheduler in the combineLatest for run drain (instead of call it directly from combine)
- ObservableOn "leaf" observable on the same scheduler and share
-Only emit value from combineLatest if there is no more entry in the queue